# what is equivalent with cvSVD in openCV for android

Tags: android, opencv, matrix

I can't find the method cvSVD in opencV 2.4.2 for android. can anyone help or give me some idea ?

Comment: As you can see, [it does exist](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=svd#svd-compute) for openCV 2.4.2; can you show a relevant sample of your code?

Comment: i am looking for the method for android lib, not C++. Do you know which one is equivalent with it? now I need to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors from matrices .

Answer (score 0):

There is not. I need to code it myself. It produces eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix.
For whoever concerns, got some working javascript here to help :
http://www.akiti.ca/compRealEigSys.js